# Binding a textbox into a listview break binding without doing anything

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, textbox

im using WPF and im filling a ListView via ItemsSource and im binding each element of the source in some controls but when I try to bind a textbox it doesnt update the Source here is my code...

```
<ListView Name="LB_PedidosRepartidor" Margin="0,37,6,10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" Selector.IsSelected="False">
                <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="../IMG/Order.png" Width="25"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="N° Orden" Width="65" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Orden}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Fecha" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Fecha}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Código" Width="65" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Codigo}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Nombre" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Nombre}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Dirección" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Dirección}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Estado" Width="130">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=id_status}" DisplayMemberPath="Nombre_Estado" SelectedValuePath="id_estado" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded">
                                <ComboBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=id_status}" Value="3">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=id_status}" Value="4">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=id_status}" Value="5">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=id_status}" Value="6">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=id_status}" Value="8">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ComboBox.Style>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Informacion" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Info}" Width="180"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn> 
                <GridViewColumn Header="Factura" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Factura}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Paqueteria" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Paqueteria}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

This is the code to fill te listview with a datatable

```
private void GetOrdersFrom()
    {
        if (CB_Repartidor.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder oSB = new StringBuilder();
                SAPbobsCOM.Recordset oRS = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)DAL.GetCompany().GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
                DataTable oDT = new DataTable();
                DataRow oDR;
                oDT.Columns.Add("Orden", typeof(int));
                oDT.Columns.Add("Fecha");
                oDT.Columns.Add("Codigo");
                oDT.Columns.Add("Nombre");
                oDT.Columns.Add("Dirección");
                oDT.Columns.Add("id_status", typeof(int));
                oDT.Columns.Add("id_statusAnt", typeof(int));
                oDT.Columns.Add("Info", typeof(string));
                oDT.Columns.Add("ComentariosAnt", typeof(string));
                oDT.Columns.Add("Factura");
                oDT.Columns.Add("Paqueteria");
                oRS.DoQuery("SELECT id_ruta FROM emb_Repartidor WHERE Codigo = " + CB_Repartidor.SelectedValue + " AND id_ruta IS NOT NULL ");
                if (oRS.Fields.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (((DataRowView)CB_Repartidor.SelectedItem)["Status"].ToString() == "Asignado")
                        LB_PedidosRepartidor.IsEnabled = false;
                    else LB_PedidosRepartidor.IsEnabled = true;
                    id_ruta = (int)oRS.Fields.Item("id_ruta").Value;
                    oSB.Append("SELECT T1.DocEntry, Convert(varchar(30),T0.Fecha_Asignado,100) DocDueDate, T4.TrnspName, Convert(varchar(30),T1.DocDueDate,107) Date , ")
                        .Append("convert(varchar(10),dbo.FN_StringTime(T1.DocTime),108) Tiempo, T1.CardCode, T1.CardName, T1.Address, T2.Status, T3.Comentarios, ")
                        .Append(" MAX(Case T5.TargetType When 15 Then T8.DocNum When 13 Then T7.DocNum End) Factura ")
                        .Append("FROM emb_rutas_pedidos T0 INNER JOIN ORDR T1 ON T0.id_pedido = T1.DocEntry ")
                        .Append("INNER JOIN emb_pedidos T2 ON T0.id_pedido = T2.DocEntry ")
                        .Append("Inner Join (Select M0.id_ruta_pedido, MAX(M0.Status) As Status, MAX(M0.Comentarios) As Comentarios, MAX(M0.id) As ID ")
                        .Append("From dbo.emb_pedidos_status_historial M0 Group By M0.id_ruta_pedido) T3 On T0.id = T3.id_ruta_pedido ")
                        .Append("INNER JOIN OSHP T4 ON T1.TrnspCode = T4.TrnspCode ")
                        .Append("Inner Join RDR1 T5 ON T5.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry ")
                        .Append("Left Join DLN1 T6 On T5.TrgetEntry = T6.DocEntry And T5.TargetType = 15 ")
                        .Append("Left Join OINV T7 On T5.TrgetEntry = T7.DocEntry And T5.TargetType = 13 ")
                        .Append("Left Join OINV T8 On T6.TrgetEntry = T8.DocEntry And T6.TargetType = 13 ")
                        .Append("WHERE T0.id_ruta = ").Append(id_ruta)
                        .Append(" GROUP BY T1.DocEntry, T1.DocDueDate, T0.Fecha_Asignado,  T1.CardCode, T1.CardName, T1.Address, T2.Status, T3.Comentarios, T4.TrnspName, T0.Orden, T1.DocTime ")
                        .Append(" Order By T0.Orden");
                    oRS.DoQuery(oSB.ToString());
                    oRS.MoveFirst();
                    while (!oRS.EoF)
                    {
                        oDR = oDT.NewRow();
                        oDR["Orden"] = oRS.Fields.Item("DocEntry").Value;
                        oDR["Fecha"] = oRS.Fields.Item("DocDueDate").Value + "\n"+ oRS.Fields.Item("Date").Value + " " + oRS.Fields.Item("Tiempo").Value;
                        oDR["Codigo"] = oRS.Fields.Item("CardCode").Value;
                        oDR["Nombre"] = oRS.Fields.Item("CardName").Value;
                        oDR["Dirección"] = oRS.Fields.Item("Address").Value;
                        oDR["id_status"] = oRS.Fields.Item("Status").Value;
                        oDR["id_statusAnt"] = oRS.Fields.Item("Status").Value;
                        oDR["Info"] = oRS.Fields.Item("Comentarios").Value.ToString();
                        oDR["ComentariosAnt"] = oRS.Fields.Item("Comentarios").Value.ToString();
                        oDR["Factura"] = oRS.Fields.Item("Factura").Value;
                        oDR["Paqueteria"] = oRS.Fields.Item("TrnspName").Value;
                        oDT.Rows.Add(oDR);
                        oRS.MoveNext();
                    }
                    LB_PedidosRepartidor.ItemsSource = oDT.DefaultView;
                }
                else
                {
                    GetRepartidores();
                    LB_PedidosRepartidor.Items.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
```

i already try using the binding properties Mode and UpdateSourceTrigger 
Please Help me i need it

Comment: Is the Info property already pre-populated? Are you implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: do rest of the bindings work correctly e.g the selectedValue of combo for id_status? and Info is also the property in the same class as is rest of the properties?

Comment: d.moncada the info property fills with the source.Info or i dont get you...
and nit al the table including id_status work correctly only that textbox doesnt work

Comment: you will need to share how you are setting the ItemsSource of listview and the table structure containing these properties

Comment: ok well i already done that...